# talend format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz to yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

I am trying to change the date format in `txmlmap` component but its not working
i want change date format

from `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz` to `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss`

**expected output:-** `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss`

Comment: TalendDate.formatDate("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss", TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz", yourDate))

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your string to a date using your source pattern and then format that date to a string using your target pattern:

```
TalendDate.formatDate("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss", TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz", myDateString))
```

Answer (score -1):

In almost all coding languages format is text, while date is a double. That means you must first make a date of the first expression, before setting the new format of that date. But in Your case the 'T' is some kind of special format that need to be replaced with a blanck space. I have no idea about what it would look like in talend but in VB it would look like this:

```
' from yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz to yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss
DateTxt = "2022-12-01'T'22:45:10"
DateTxt = Replace(DateTxt, "'T'", " ")
MyDate = CDate(DateTxt)
MsgBox Format(MyDate, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss")
```